# How to remove an item of an array when deselecting the checkbox (angular 4)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, checkbox, accordion

I have this array of objects. In each object there is another array.

```
panels = [{
  Id: "26cfdb68-ef69-4df0-b4dc-5b9c6501b0dd",
  Name: "Celiac test",
  Tests: [{
      Id: "e2bb4607-c227-4483-a3e9-55c1bc5a6781",
      Name: "test 1 (DGP) IgG"
    },
    {
      Id: "e2bb4607-c227-4483-a3e9-55c1bc5a6781",
      Name: "test 2 (DGP) IgG"
    },
    {
      Id: "e2bb4607-c227-4483-a3e9-55c1bc5a6781",
      Name: "test 3 (DGP) IgG"
    }
  ]
}],
```

I have mapped it to a bootstrap accordion with checkboxes.

First there is a checkbox for the main object, then checkboxes for the array within that object.

What I want is that when I click on the main Panel checkbox it should select the Tests checkboxes and save the panel object in the object variable, say **selectedPanel**, and when I deselect the main Panel it should deselect all the Tests checkboxes too.

That I can do, but the main thing is that when I deselect one of the Tests checkboxes it should be removed from selectedPanel and the length also.

Can anyone help me in this regard?

I have created a stackblitz too:

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mvbwtr)

Comment: so when i  deselect the checkbox you want to remove the element from the `panels` array am i correct?

Comment: yes that's what i want @YashRami

Comment: @usmansaleem Do you want this?https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bslndo

Comment: yes but how to add it in selectedPanel variable and when i comeback for edit it should stay thay way?

Comment: will you selectedPanel hold the whole category object or just a test child?

Comment: Also can you explain this `when i comeback for edit it should stay thay way?`

Comment: the whole object 
like when i select panel it will select whole tests and i deselect some and click on button add test and comeback every test is checked

Comment: https://codeshare.io/Gq97kM 
this is my actual code

Comment: @usmansaleem check my answer to see if this the behavior you want to acheive

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this.

```
<ngb-accordion #acc="ngbAccordion">
  <ngb-panel *ngFor="let panel of panels; let i = index" id="{{panel.Id}}" [title]="panel.Name">
     <ng-template ngbPanelTitle>
        <span class="panel-length"><strong>{{panel.Tests.length}}</strong></span>

            <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input ml-5" id="{{panel.Id}}" name="{{panel.Name}}">


      </ng-template>
    <ng-template ngbPanelContent>
    <div class="individual-panel" *ngFor="let test of panel.Tests, let j = index;">
          <span class="text-dimmed">{{test.Name}}</span>
            <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input ml-5" id="{{test.Id}}" name="{{test.Name}}" (click)="checkItem(i, j)">  
        </div>
    </ng-template>
  </ngb-panel>
</ngb-accordion>

   <!-- <span class="panel-length"><strong>{{panels.Tests.length}}</strong></span> -->
```

**TS**

```
checkItem(i, j){
   this.panels[i].Tests.splice(j, 1);
   console.log(this.panels[i].Tests);
  }
```

I hope it helps you out.

Comment: it is removing the whole row from the array.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a short Stackblitz demo [HERE](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nested-checkboxes)

It controls the toggle of child checkboxes using parent and each checkbox has a `checked` parameter to track which one is selected.

This would make it easier for you to maintain state of each checkbox rather than manipulating on each change.

Comment: yes but how to add it in selectedPanel variable and when i comeback for edit it should stay thay way?

Answer (score 0):

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bsszc9?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Please note that the code below is a quick example of a technique you could use.

I gave the tests an isShown property. Note: You should refactor these tests into objects with their separate module.

```
panels = [{
  CategoryId: "31b7a227-9fda-4d14-8e1f-1dee5beeccb4",
  Id: "26cfdb68-ef69-4df0-b4dc-5b9c6501b0dd",
  Name: "Celiac test",
  Tests: [
  {Id: "e2bb4607-c227-4483-a3e9-55c1bc5a6781",
   Name: "test 1 (DGP) IgG", 
   isShown: true },
  {
   Id: "e2bb4607-c227-4483-a3e9-55c1bc5a6781",
   Name: "test 2 (DGP) IgG", 
   isShown: true },
  {
   Id: "e2bb4607-c227-4483-a3e9-55c1bc5a6781",
   Name: "test 3 (DGP) IgG", 
   isShown: true}
]
},
{
  CategoryId: "31b7a227-9fda-4d14-8e1f-1dee5beeccb4",
  Id: "26cfdb68-ef69-4df0-b4dc-5b9c6501b0dd",
  Name: "Comprehensive test",
  Tests: [
  {Id: "e2bb4607-c227-4483-a3e9-55c1bc5a6781",
   Name: "test 1  (DGP) IgG"},
  {
   Id: "e2bb4607-c227-4483-a3e9-55c1bc5a6781",
   Name: "test 2  (DGP) IgG"},
  {
   Id: "e2bb4607-c227-4483-a3e9-55c1bc5a6781",
   Name: "test 3  (DGP) IgG"}
]
}]
```

When you click the input box a click event is triggered and sets the `test.isShown` property to `false`. The `*ngIf` would hide the test from the displayed code. ( note that I introduced a new ng-container because you cannot use `*ngFor` and `*ngIf` on the same container ).

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let test of panel.Tests">
  <div class="individual-panel" *ngIf='test.isShown'>
    <span class="text-dimmed">{{test.Name}}</span>
    <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input ml-5" id="{{test.Id}}" name="{{test.Name}}" (click)="hide( test )" >   
  </div>
</ng-container>
```

Below is the method that is triggered by the click event. Alternatively you could remove the `test` out of the array ( that would make your counter work, but it may not be a good idea to erase data );

```
hide( test ) {
  test.isShown = false;
}
```

On a final note, this answer is to show you this simple technique. You obviously want to refactor in smaller classes/modules and make this more maintainable. Hope it helps ;).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to added an extra attribute to your `panels` and `Tests` to store the state of your checkboxes.
You `panels` array would be like this:

```
panels = [{
  Id: "26cfdb68-ef69-4df0-b4dc-5b9c6501b0dd",
  Name: "Celiac test",
  checked: false,
  Tests: [{
      Id: "e2bb4607-c227-4483-a3e9-55c1bc5a6781",
      Name: "test 1 (DGP) IgG",
      checked: false
    },
    {
      Id: "e2bb4607-c227-4483-a3e9-55c1bc5a6781",
      Name: "test 2 (DGP) IgG",
      checked: false
    },
    {
      Id: "e2bb4607-c227-4483-a3e9-55c1bc5a6781",
      Name: "test 3 (DGP) IgG",
      checked: false
    }
  ]
}]
```

Second you need to check the value of the checkbox to decide whether you want to keep that specific test in your `selectedPanel` of not.

> I'm assuming that your `panels` and `Tests` have unique Id attribute

You can find the updated version of your **stackblitz** [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bxt5un?file=src%2Fapp%2Faccordion-toggle.ts)

I hope this is the behavior you want to achieve.

Comment: what if there is no checked coming from backend and also it isn't working as it isn't letting me add 2 or more panels just one 
also can you manipulate my code so that i can understand it better codeshare.io/Gq97kM

panelIds is the one where all the panel's id is 
and selectedPanels has whole array of objects

Comment: as i have showing length of selected tests on next page 
it is giving me error


 let rollup = session.SelectedPanels.reduce((memo, panel) => {
        memo[panel.CategoryId] =
          (memo[panel.CategoryId] || 0) +
          (panel.Tests.length > 0 ? panel.Tests.length : 1);
        return memo;
      }, {});

      this.categoryRollup =
        session.SelectedPanels.length > 0
          ? Object.assign({}, this.categoryRollup, rollup)
          : {};